# Collapse all accordins on page load - jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery accordions.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>section one</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus        nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
<h3>Browse Authors</h3>
<div>
  <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
</div>

</div>
```

I have this stuff in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true

});
});
</script>
```

Using the above I get collapsible accordions. The first one is open on page load.

Does anyone know what setting that I can use to make it start with all accordions closed?

Comment: You should have just check the DOC...

Comment: its basic change in the accordion plugin...

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)-option when you initialize your accordion:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

The boolean `false` will collapse all panels (require the option `collapsible` with true).
Setting an integer will open the the panel according to its index.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7yLx8L/)**